# SQL FREETEXT Search Escaping Space

Tags: sql, full-text-search, freetext, thesaurus

I have a Thesaurus table in my database, I want to collect data using FREETEXT. However the string I'm searching for contains spaces.

For example, I want to search for the code "AB 001"

```
select * 
from TheThesaurus
where freetext(TheDefinition, 'AB 001')
```

This code will search for both "AB" and "001", which will give me a lot more junk results. I tried putting the string in double quotes, but it's not working either.

```
select * 
from TheThesaurus
where freetext(TheDefinition, '"AB 001"')
```

How can I do so I can search for the full "AB 001" string??

I used LIKE and it's giving me the desired result, but I want to try full-text search since it is much faster and will give more accurate result in my case.

```
select * 
from TheThesaurus
where TheDefinition LIKE '%AB 001%'
```

Thanks!

### EDIT

I tried using `CONTAINS`, but it was giving me extra results that I could not understand why they are being returned. The `CONTAINS` function doesn't work for me either :/

```
select * 
from TheThesaurus
where Contains(TheDefinition, 'AB%001')
```

Answer (score 0):

The query

select * 
from TheThesaurus
where Contains(TheDefinition, '"AB 001"')

will give you phrase search with the correct result